# "Last Name" Sharepoint problem

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Field in my Sharepoint List with the Full name of a client. But a i need to get the First Name + Last name to create an email. The problem is:

1 - Some names has more than 1 surname. Ex: Fred Duque Cornwall

2 - I tried to create a camp "Last Name" with the calc (=RIGHT([Client],5)) but appears a message error.

3 - I tried to use the calc (=RIGHT([Client], LEN([Client)-8)) in the same fiel too, but failed. That calc is on the Sharepoint Documentation but doesn't works. Apparently "LEN" doesn't fit anymore, despite appearing in the documentation.

What sould i do ? Someone could help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the sample formulas below:

First Name:

```
=LEFT([Client],(FIND(" ",[Client])-1))
```

Last Name:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",[Client],FIND(" ",[Client])+1)),RIGHT([Client],LEN([Client])-FIND(" ",[Client])),RIGHT([Client],LEN([Client])-FIND(" ",[Client],FIND(" ",[Client])+1)))
```

Output:

[image]

References: [IS functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087), [LEFT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-function-913824b4-fc42-4c8c-9229-0eaa57dcdf49), [RIGHT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-function-112699e2-fe7e-4cbf-8d1e-0e8db3884f26), [FIND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-function-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f).

Comment: THANKS!!! Helps me  A LOT!

Comment: @VíctorMarri Would you please mark this reply as the answer or give a vote if it helps?